# Polynomial equation root

Tags: polynomials, roots

I need to show whether:

$$\frac{1}{x}\times A - \left(\frac{1}{(x+b)(x-b)}-\frac{1}{(x+c)(c-x)}\right)$$

has a single root between $b$ and $c$, where $c>b>0$ and $A>0$. My numerical plots suggest so, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Can you check the term in the brackets? Is $ c-x$ intended? If so, can you write it as $ + 1/ (x+c)(x-c)$ to preserve similarity?

Comment: @Calvin Lin: Absolutely agree! The $O.P.$. either he is careless or he wanted to "confuse" his question a bit. Both positions are undesirable.

Comment: Sorry about that. The form I have here (which is taken from my original problem), ensures that denominators are positive. There is an economics-based interpretation to that, apologies if it makes the question more difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have:

$$P(x)=\frac Ax - \frac{1}{x^2-b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2-x^2}$$

To show that the root exists, you need only show that $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} P(b+\epsilon)=-\infty \text{ and } \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} P(c-\epsilon)=\infty$$

Since the function is continuous whenever $x$ is not $0, \pm b, \pm c$ it is continuous on the range $(b, c)$ as defined, and therefore the intermediate value theorem proves the root exists.

Comment: A single root has been required.

Comment: @Piquito. A single root between $b$ and $c$

Comment: @Claude Leibovici: Of course, that is understood.

Comment: @Piquito There is a single root to the given function in that range.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion above and the limits, there exists at least one root where $P(x)$ crosses zero from below.

If the function $P(x)$ had multiple roots, then there exists an $x^\star\in\left[b,c\right]$ such that $P(x^\star)\leq 0$ and $P^\prime(x^\star)<0$ (i.e., when $P(x)$ crosses zero from above).

I show there is no such $x^\star$.

First off, we note that:
$$P^\prime\left(x\right)=\frac{2 x \left(-2 x^2 \left(b^2+c^2\right)+b^4+c^4+2 x^4\right)}{\left(b^2-x^2\right)^2 \left(x^2-c^2\right)^2}-\frac{A}{x^2}.$$

It follows that $P^\prime(x)<0$ if and only if

$$A>\overline{A}=\frac{2 x^3 \left(-2 b^2 x^2+b^4-2 c^2 x^2+c^4+2 x^4\right)}{\left(b^2-x^2\right)^2 \left(x^2-c^2\right)^2}.$$

Next, we see that
$$P\left(x,\overline{A}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{(b+x)^2}+\frac{1}{(b-x)^2}+\frac{1}{(c-x)^2}+\frac{1}{(c+x)^2}\right)>0.$$

Since $P$ increases in $A$, it follows that $P\left(x,A\right)>0$,  $\forall A\geq \overline{A}$. Therefore,
$$ P^\prime\left(x\right)<0 \Longrightarrow P\left(x\right)>0 $$
and there is no root $x^\star$. In other words, every time the function decreases, it remains positive -- and it never crosses zero from above.

Correct?

Answer (score 0):

The argumentation in you're answer seems to be correct, although I haven't calculated it all.

You should add the possibility, that P only "touches" the x-axis in $x^*$. Consider for example the square function, where $f'(0)=0$. That means, P hasn't to cross the root. But I think, that's easily solved by adding some $\leq$.